Where is the Cf cap in this design?
I am using WEBENCH from TI for the LM2596SX-5.0/NOPB buck converter. It is a Cf cap in the  "BILL OF MATERIALS" that doesn't appear on the schematic. Do you know where is that from?



This sounds like a question for TI's support. Have you contacted them? What have they suggested?

The LM2596 datasheet mentions a  Feedforward Capacitor (CFF):

While this is CFF, rather than the Cf given in the TI WEBBENCH BOM, the datasheet does say the compensation capacitor value is typically is in the range 100 pF to 33 nF. The Cf in the TI WEBBENCH BOM has value of 3.3 nF, which is within the datasheet suggested range for CFF.
Therefore, think the Cf in the TI WEBBENCH BOM could have been intended to connected to the FB pin of the LM2596 in some way.
I'm not a user of the TI WEBBENCH, but the TI Simulation, hardware & system design tools forum could be the place to ask for a more definitive answer.

From additional information in a comment:

I didn't mention this, but I selected the output voltage as 5V and the output current as 2.5A so does that mean that I don't need the Cf cap? – Robert

The datasheet has the following in section 9.1.2 Feedforward Capacitor (CFF):

A feedforward capacitor, shown across R2 in Table 9-6, is used when the output voltage is greater than 10 V or when COUT has a very low ESR. This capacitor adds lead compensation to the feedback loop and increases the phase margin for better loop stability. For CFF selection, see the Section 9.2.2.2 section.

The TI WEBBENCH BOM shows has selected a Cout which has a ESR of 90 mΩ. From the datasheet I can't seem to find what value is considered very low ESR for COUT. I.e. even with a 5V output voltage, depending upon the ESR of COUT then CFF might still be required.

I didn't mention this, but I selected the output voltage as 5V and the output current as 2.5A so does that mean that I don't need the Cf cap?

@Robert I have updated the answer about the need for the Cf cap. Also suggest you edit the question to add the selection of the output voltage and current which were selected in WEBBENCH, in case that helps you to get other answers.
